# Ordering filtered results

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method which under code review gives me a CA1502 avoid excessive complexity error (although if I suppress the message it will build fine):

```
private void OrderResults()
{
    switch (_orderColumn)
    {
        case 0:
        default:
            _fitleredResults = _orderDirection.Equals("desc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? _fitleredResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.Street) : _fitleredResults.OrderBy(x => x.Street);
            break;

        case 1:
            _fitleredResults = _orderDirection.Equals("desc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? _fitleredResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.Street) : _fitleredResults.OrderBy(x => x.Street);
            break;

        case 2:
            _fitleredResults = _orderDirection.Equals("desc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? _fitleredResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.City) : _fitleredResults.OrderBy(x => x.City);
            break;

        case 3:
            _fitleredResults = _orderDirection.Equals("desc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? _fitleredResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.Country) : _fitleredResults.OrderBy(x => x.Country);
            break;

        case 4:
            _fitleredResults = _orderDirection.Equals("desc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? _fitleredResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.RecID) : _fitleredResults.OrderBy(x => x.RecID);
            break;
    }
}
```

Explanation of variables:

- `_filteredResults` is an `IEnumerable<AddressObject>`;
- `_orderColumn` is an int passed in by jQuery `DataTable`s and doesn't match the property indexes (which is why I was mapping it using a switch)

Address object class:

```
public class AddressObject
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string CountryRegionID { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    public long RecID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to make this code less complex?

Comment: It is possible to use Expression Trees to generate dynamic queries [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx). This seems be to what you are looking for.  I will say though that these seems more like a Stackoverflow question than a CodeReview one.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out the link.  Sorry about the question, I thought the site was for asking people to review the code you have that already works and suggest improvements.  Perhaps I should have worded it differently or not specifically asked about `func`

Comment: if you are getting an error that means it doesn't work, right?

Comment: @Lyle'sMug Just a code review error, not an actual build error

Comment: gotcha,  you should reword that in your question, that is what I was thinking it was, but wasn't sure.

Comment: What type is `_filteredResults` and is this entity framework or another ORM? I can see other things worthy of pointing out here which make it worthy of answering

Comment: @RobH have edited to include more information.  It is EF although the initial dataset is got from the cache before filtering is applied

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your `case 1` case is identical to your `case 0`,`default` case (order by street). Is that intentional? It looks like a mistake to me because you've cascaded 0 and default but **not** 1. If it isn't a mistake, and they do all have the same behaviour you should cascade them all or let them all be picked up by the `default` case.

I normally see `default` as the last option in a switch statement, I feel like that might be a convention but don't have anything to back it up.

You're repeating this code a lot: `_orderDirection.Equals("desc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` put it in a variable (which will make the code more readable.

So far:

```
private void OrderResults()
{
    var isDescending = _orderDirection.Equals("desc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    switch (_orderColumn)
    {    
        case 2:
            _fitleredResults = isDescending ? _fitleredResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.City) : _fitleredResults.OrderBy(x => x.City);
            break;
        case 3:
            _fitleredResults = isDescending ? _fitleredResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.Country) : _fitleredResults.OrderBy(x => x.Country);
            break;
        case 4:
            _fitleredResults = isDescending ? _fitleredResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.RecID) : _fitleredResults.OrderBy(x => x.RecID);
            break;
        default:
            _fitleredResults = isDescending ? _fitleredResults.OrderByDescending(x => x.Street) : _fitleredResults.OrderBy(x => x.Street);
            break;
    }
}
```

As Heslsacher says, you could further improve by using named constants for the indexes.

I did write some additional stuff about using a method to get a Func but then I realised that `RectId` is a long so it all went out the window.

**Edit**

For posterity, I'll add in what I had written:

```
private void OrderResults()
{
    var isDescending = _orderDirection.Equals("desc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    var sortProperty = GetSortProperty();
    if (isDescending)
    {
        _filteredResults = _filteredResults.OrderByDescending(sortProperty);
    }
    else
    {
        _filteredResults = _filteredResults.OrderBy(sortProperty);
    }
}

private Func<AddressObject, object> GetSortProperty()
{
    switch(_orderColumn)
    {
        case 2:
            return x => x.City;
        case 3:
            return x => x.Country;
        case 4:
            return x => x.RectId;
        default: 
            return x => x.Street;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry was a typo adding the string comparison to a bool is a good idea but didn't fully solve the complexity issues

Comment: @Pete - updated answer with what I had before, all typed directly into browser so unsure if it will compile/work.

Comment: Now that looks nice.

Comment: Aha, that's what I was after.  Thanks! And even fixed my typo on _filteredResults!

Comment: @Pete - didn't even notice that, I just typed the second bit fresh so didn't make the mistake ;).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this line:

```
_orderDirection.Equals("desc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

is coming back everywhere. So you can place it before the switch statement and place it in a variable:

```
var sortDescending = _orderDirection.Equals("desc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Now with the help of relection and a `Func<T, TResult>` delegate, you can make the switch less complex and redundant:

```
public object GetPropertyInfo<T>(string propertyName, T obj)
{
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    return property.GetValue(obj, null);
}

public IEnumerable<T> OrderedBy<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, string propertyName, bool sortDescending)
{
    Func<T, object> sortRule = x => GetPropertyInfo<T>(propertyName, x);
    return sortDescending ? items.OrderByDescending(sortRule) : items.OrderBy(sortRule);
}
```

And now you can use your code like following:

```
private void OrderResults()
{
    var sortDescending = _orderDirection.Equals("desc", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

    switch (_orderColumn)
    {
        case 0: _fitleredResults = OrderedBy(_fitleredResults, "Street", sortDescending); break;
        case 2: _fitleredResults = OrderedBy(_fitleredResults, "City", sortDescending); break;
        //...
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

You can also throw all the above code in one extension method:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> OrderedBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items,  string propertyName, bool sortDescending)
    {
        var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
        Func<T, object> sortRule = x =>  property.GetValue(x, null);
        return sortDescending ? items.OrderByDescending(sortRule) : items.OrderBy(sortRule);
    }
}
```

And use it as follows:

```
_fitleredResults = _fitleredResults.OrderedBy("Street", sortDescending);
```